# get URL from xml in to Flash AS3

Tags: xml, flash

Im trying to get a flash file get the URL from a XML file, but when I check my trace in flash i get undefind. Can't figure out why it's not working.

This is my xml:

```
<?XML version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<link targ="_self" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com"> </link>
```

and my actionscript in as2 on my button:

```
on (Release)
{
urlXML = new XML();
urlXML.ignoreWhite = true;
urlXML.load("xmlurl.xml");
urlXML.onLoad = function (success)
{
}
  trace("success is "+success);
  var url = urlXML.firstChild.attributes.href;
  trace("url = "+url);

  {
      trace("pressed with "+url);
    getURL(url);
  }

}
```

Can someone give me some guidelins how to get his right

Thanks!

Comment: try : `urlXML.firstChild.childNodes.attributes.href;` or `urlXML.firstChild.childNodes[0].attributes.href;`

Answer (score 2):

that's because you have empty function body:

```
urlXML.onLoad = function (success)
{
  trace(success);
}
// not ->> 
urlXML.onLoad = function (success)
{
}
trace(success);
```

Comment: Thanks, after this changes I got "success is true" in the output. But still it looks like it's not fetching the URL from the xml, cause trace("url "+url) is undefinded.